# Best independent database for use with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, database, vb.net, entity-framework

What is the best independent database (no installation required, runs directly from .dlls) that I could use with Entity Framework? Also, few .dlls are a plus.

Comment: How do you define "best"?

Answer (score 6):

`SQLite` is one such independent DB(no installation required, runs directly from .dlls).

Comment: +1. Just to add there is a good article on another site for doing just such. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/236918/Using-SQLite-embedded-database-with-entity-framewo

Answer (score 0):

There's also SQL Compact (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ff687142.aspx).  Its featureset is somewhat limited compared to its big brother, though.

Some limitations: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc835494.aspx

> •SQL Server Compact 4.0 supports entities with server-generated
>   values, but only for identity columns. If your model maps to
>   non-identity columns with server-generated values, a "Not supported"
>   exception is thrown.
>
> •SQL Server Compact 4.0 does not support schemas with duplicate
>   constraint names.
>
> In SQL Server Compact, the constraint names are unique within a table
>   and this can allow duplicate constraint names in the database. The
>   behavior is different from SQL Server, where the constraint names are
>   unique across the database. If a SQL Server Compact 4.0 schema has
>   duplicate referential integrity (primary key – foreign key
>   relationship) constraint names, the generation of the Entity Data
>   Model using the Entity Data Model Wizard will fail. You should always
>   keep the constraint name unique across the database, like by adding
>   the name of the table to the constraint name.
>
> •SQL Server Compact does not support DISTINCT in aggregates (max, min,
>   sum, count).
>
> •SQL Server Compact does not support command time-outs when it is used
>   with the Entity Framework.
>
> •SQL Server Compact supports only Unicode strings.
>
> •SQL Server Compact does not support stored procedures and views.